# Avoid trigger trigger execution several times - Best Practices

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice, recursion

I've been looking for a while for best practices when trying to avoid recursive trigger execution, but I haven't really found anything that I like.

At the moment, the most straight forward solution I know is to implement a small flag variable,

```
public static Boolean hasAlreadyExecuted = false;
```

and afterward simply check the flag before allowing any logic to be executed,

```
public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so)
{
    if(!hasAlreadyExecuted)
    {
        // Do some magic with the record
    }
}
```

Nonetheless, I was wondering if any of you know any other methods worth commenting. At the moment, most of the times, I use a trigger-handler-helper framework to control execution, but it doesn't have any tools to help me control this, so I basically implement stuff like I commented above to solve it.

Comment: This is an interesting question but I'm sorry it seems like it doesn't fit the rules  here. This is too primarily opinion-based.  Your solution seems good. The static flag is a known pattern for this case.

Comment: @MartinLezer oh. I didn't think of it that way... Sorry for the inconvenient, I just thought stack would be the best place to ask something like this.

Comment: No problem. Looks like people disagree with me and I'm glad. Hope you'll get your answer !

Comment: Updated my answer with another slighter better technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not going to go with a full-blown trigger framework (these frameworks often handle recursion), then you can go with something like my `TriggerControl` object.

It uses the static variable concept, but is able to keep track of this per `sObject` which is good if you are dealing with a complex set of triggers interacting with each other.

Try this:

```
public class TriggerControl {

  @testVisible
  private static Map<System.Type, Boolean> hasRunMap = new Map<System.Type, Boolean>{
    Event.class => false,
    Opportunity.class => false
  };
  public static Boolean hasRun(System.Type entityType) {
    if (hasRunMap.containsKey(entityType)) {
      return hasRunMap.get(entityType);
    }
    return false;
  }
  public static void setHasRun(System.Type entityType) {
    hasRunMap.put(entityType, true);
  }
  public static void clearHasRun(System.Type entityType) {
    hasRunMap.put(entityType, false);
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
if (TriggerControl.hasRun(Event.class)){
  return;
}
else {
  TriggerControl.setHasRun(Event.class);
}
```

There are some improvements you can make (calling set has run in the hasRun() check) but it works quite well for me when I'm doing small projects.

This approach has some drawbacks, as Eric mentioned.

If you wanted to get a bit fancier, you could try using a per Object per Id, per major functionality method.

First you'd define your major functions in a metadata type - say

- `Event - change status - 1 recurse`
- `Event - update whoId - 2 recursions`
- `Account - copy opportunity data - 1 recursion`

Then, you could create a multilevel map (or use a multipart key like `Event_ChangeStatus_a00230000rhtrgh`

You could use this map or key to generate lists of records to pass to each of these helper functions.

This way you could achieve more granularity by restricting recursion at the functional level rather than the object level.

Comment: Thanks Caspar! It is indeed the same static flag principle, but a little more elaborated. Interesting approach

Answer (score 3):

If you use what you've written in your question, it MUST be placed in an external class. Otherwise, a new instantiation of the same class running at the same time will see the boolean variable as being in the same context as another class that's running concurrently. This will cause your 2nd trigger handler class to fail if the recursion prevention boolean has already been set.

As others have noted, you'd also want to set this variable by trigger class. This is one of the many reasons that trigger frameworks are superior to base triggers that call handler classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky problem. The ideal solution is to write triggers that only do something when the data matches a specific pattern - e.g. a field value changes - so that the recursion stops naturally. So avoiding recursion isn't something that can always be done in a framework independently of the specific logic.

The boolean flag approach (or keeping a set of Id values) while simple are both potentially broken. For the boolean flag, what if the set of records involved in the second execution is different than the first execution? While a set of Id values can avoid that problem, the field values might be different in the second execution so requiring different trigger output. These amount to quick fixes when you find a problem: you are typically relying on good luck (or more ideally careful analysis of the situation) that no data inconsistencies are introduced.

Comment: As you said, the ideal solution would be to write well organized triggers, but sometimes when we start to work on a legacy org with all kinds of classes and triggers, it's complicated. I myself was facing an org with +50 triggers this morning... and damn. Thanks for the insight though, I hadn't thought of it :)

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano If the org is blowing up, step 1 of the fix is for sure a pragmatic fix like Caspar's (unless you are writing a banking application where  you probably don't want account balances to accidentally have money added or taken away because a trigger's execution doesn't happen when it should).